# Android application wide sensor listener design pattern?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, android-library

I am designing library related to **sensors** and will allow other apps to integrate this library and **listen for specific gestures on their own app such as shake/tilt** and as a result something happen like new activity appear from library.

But integration of library should be **as easy as possible**.

First way letting developers create custom `Application` class and init my library with following way.

```
MyLibrary lib = new MyLibrary(appContext);
lib.startListening();
```

But problem here is that I have operation related to activity context like startingActivity or getting root view. This is not quite possible if I give context at `Application` class (can not understand activity from app context)

Other way would be implement or inject this library in every activity inside app with `onCreate()` method.

```
lib.startListening(activityContext);
```

and unregister `onDestroy()` and related methods.

```
lib.stopListening();
```

The problem is I don't like second path and love the simplicity of the first way. Is there anything I am missing in the first way to make it possible?

[Edit]: Third way would be extending custom activity class but thats hardly viable solution for me, I don't think user will integrate my library just for such small functionality and change regular `Activity` extend operation to my obscure custom `Activity` class.

[Edit]: I think `Service` is right way to go. But still interested in alternative patterns.

Comment: I know that it might be not much of a help but take a look at ACRA project. It works the way you want. Maybe you will find something helpful there.

Comment: I will look at it, it might help. Thanks.